# Angular Chart color does not change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I'm creating some charts for my simple application.

Though the chart is created but colors are not applied on it. 
Even i have check with default one, they are also not applied on it.

But strange thing is that another chart in same page has colors.

this chart canvas

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-options="options"
                        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" 
                        chart-colours="colours" height="100px">  </canvas>
```

This is its controller

```
app.controller("charByMonth", function ($scope,$http) {

$scope.totalAmount=0;
  $scope.labels = [];
  $scope.series = ['Amount'];
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.colours = ['#803690','#00ADF9', '#DCDCDC', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'];
  $scope.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    };

  $scope.showCustomizedChart = function(){

        $scope.labels=[];
        $scope.data = [];

        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAmountByMonth/'+$scope.selectedYear+'/'+$scope.selectedStartMonth+'/'+$scope.selectedEndMonth)
        .then(function(response){
            for(var i=$scope.selectedStartMonth;i<=$scope.selectedEndMonth;i++){
                switch(i){
                case 1:
                    $scope.labels.push("JAN");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $scope.labels.push("FEB");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $scope.labels.push("MAR");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $scope.labels.push("APR");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $scope.labels.push("MAY");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $scope.labels.push("JUN");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $scope.labels.push("JUL");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    $scope.labels.push("AUG");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    $scope.labels.push("SEP");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    $scope.labels.push("OCT");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    $scope.labels.push("NOV");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    $scope.labels.push("DEC");
                    break;
                }
            }

            $scope.data.push(response.data);
            console.log($scope.data);
        });
    }

});
```

This is the chart i get

[image]

While in same page before this chart i'm creating another chart and that chart is colorful

this is the image of that chart

[image]

and this is its controller

```
app.controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {
  $scope.totalAmount=0;
  $scope.labels = [];
  $scope.series = ['Amount'];
  $scope.colours = ['#803690','#00ADF9', '#DCDCDC', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'];
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    };

  getYearsData = function(){
      $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAmountByYear').then(function(response){
          var wholedata = response.data;
          angular.forEach(wholedata,function(value,key){
            $scope.totalAmount = value.totalAmount;
            console.log($scope.totalAmount);
            var checkSize = value.years.length;
            if($scope.labels.length !== checkSize){
                for(var i=0;i<checkSize;i++){
                    $scope.labels.push(value.years[i].toString());
                }
                console.log($scope.labels);
            }

            var checkSizeAmount = value.amount.length;
            if($scope.data.length !== checkSizeAmount){
                for(var i=0;i<checkSizeAmount;i++){
                    $scope.data.push(value.amount[i]);
                }

                console.log($scope.data);
            }

          });
      });
  }


  getYearsData();
});
```

My Second Problem is that the chart populates wrong from data.

This is the data

[image]

and this is what i get in chart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace **chart-colours** by **chart-colors**